# Should table heading units follow a slash or be in parentheses?

Tags: computer-science, writing-style, physics

What is the standard in Computer Science and Physics?

| Independent variable (units) | Dependent variable (units) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 9 |

or

| Independent variable / units | Dependent variable / units |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 9 |

Comment: Can you provide us with published examples of tables using one of these formats?

Comment: Hi, I thought of closing this as duplicate of the other one because labelling practices and guidelines are virtually the same between graphs and tables. Let me know if you have any specific objection.

Comment: @GEdgar There are actually plenty of examples of both usages in the literature. Unfortunately, some have objections about using the second form, even though it's the recommended one within the International System of Units.